# MacBook Pro: Wireless connected with Airport but internet not working?

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard. When I turned it on this morning, its wireless icon was showing full network access just one point less.

However I am not able browse the Internet/websites using my MacBook Pro. I am able to use the Internet through my other laptop and phone on the same wireless network (using a TP-Link device).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God I found it. Here it is

Try turning off the security on your router first.
Then reset the router. 
Open the MacBook network preferences go to advanced setting for the airport.

Delete your network connection. Now turn off your airport then turn it back on.

Find your network again and connect now that the security if off.

When this is done restart your MacBook. You should be able to connect now. This worked for me.

I did not want to keep my network open so I then added the WPA2 security if you have it or use WPA pick a password and then start the process again.

Reset the router.

Open the MacBook network preferences go to advanced setting for the airport.

Delete your network connection. Now turn off your airport then turn it back on.

Find your network again and connect putting in the password this time.

Now restart the MacBook and with some luck you should be good to go.

I was ready to throw my MacBook out a window before I figured this out.

Good luck :)

[Thanks to](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2159149?start=0&tstart=0)